# H.264 (High 4:4:4 Profile) is not installed

Tags: video, icons, vlc, ffmpeg

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.  Many of videos are not playing. The error is "H.264 (High 4:4:4 Profile) decoder is required to play the file".
I searched the Internet and found that many people are facing this problem. I did not find any solution for this.  I can play the videos with vlc and also with ffmpeg. I do not see the icon_pics of the video in file explorer, which means that default application cannot still play them. I even installed restricted-extras, as was advised in one post.
I also installed gstreamer1.0-libav and mpv. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: First of all, did you click on the "find in ubuntu software" option and install all of the software shown? If not, it might be a good idea to do so. In addition to the `gstreamer1.0-libav`, you also need the `gstreamer1.0-plugins-good` and `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` and `gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly`

Comment: It is not clear if Ubuntu 22.04 was installed or upgraded.

Comment: However, one difference between 22.04 and older Ubuntu versions is that the `libopenh264-cisco6` and `libopenh264-6` packages are now available through apt-get and/or through the Ubuntu software app.

Comment: Actually, you should only need `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` if `libopenh264-6` or `libopenh264-cisco6` is already installed.

Comment: Although, ugly might be needed because `apt-cache show gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly` (for me on an older version of Ubuntu) shows: `video/x-h264` AND `high-4:4:4` Again, 22.04 has openh264 and older versions did not. The first route is usually to install the good, bad, and ugly plugins and if that doesn't work then try something else. In this case, I think something else would be to install one of the libopenh264 packages.